# Why RVM requires YAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rvm

While installing RVM from, it is suggested to provide YAML source tar as well.
Don't know why YAML is needed by RVM? ( **link :-https://github.com/rvm/rvm-site/blob/master/content/rvm/offline.md**)
We can very well install it as a separate gem , right?

Please provide your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is [part of Ruby's standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) and is thus shipped with Ruby itself. In order to compile Ruby with YAML support, you thus need libyaml installed. Since YAML is quite popular in Ruby and is e.g. used to specify all the metadata in packaged Rubygems, a Ruby without YAML is not very useful nowadays.

Now, some time ago, there was [a pretty nasty bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubysec-announce/3sx25iR7yHQ) in libyaml (the library used by Ruby to parse and generate YAML). In versions <= 0.1.4, it was possible to execute arbitrary code by making the ruby process parse a specially crafted yaml source.

Because of this, RVM usually downloads and compiles an up-to-date version of libyaml to ensure the compiles Rubies are safe from this vulnerability.